# Set showing duplicate data as well in Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I created a set which is showing duplicate data. How is it possible?

```
Set<Account> s = new Set<Account>();

Account a1 = new Account(Name='Hello1',NumberofEmployees=20);
Account a2 = new Account(Name='Hello2',NumberofEmployees=20);
Account a3 = new Account(Name='Hello3',NumberofEmployees=20);
Account a4 = new Account(Name='Hello4');
Account a5 = new Account(Name='Hello1');

s.add(a1);
s.add(a2);
s.add(a3);
s.add(a4);
s.add(a5);

System.debug(s);

a4.NumberOfEmployees = 30;
a5.NumberOfEmployees = 20;

System.debug(s);

System.debug('----------Loop---------');

for (Account acc: s) {
    System.debug(acc);
}
```

**Debug Report**

```
DEBUG|{Account:{Name=Hello1}, Account:{Name=Hello1, NumberOfEmployees=20}, Account:{Name=Hello2, NumberOfEmployees=20}, Account:{Name=Hello3, NumberOfEmployees=20}, Account:{Name=Hello4}}

DEBUG|{Account:{Name=Hello1, NumberOfEmployees=20}, Account:{Name=Hello2, NumberOfEmployees=20}, Account:{Name=Hello3, NumberOfEmployees=20}, Account:{Name=Hello4, NumberOfEmployees=30}}

DEBUG|-------Loop--------

DEBUG|Account:{Name=Hello1, NumberOfEmployees=20}
DEBUG|Account:{Name=Hello2, NumberOfEmployees=20}
DEBUG|Account:{Name=Hello3, NumberOfEmployees=20}
DEBUG|Account:{Name=Hello4, NumberOfEmployees=30}
DEBUG|Account:{Name=Hello1, NumberOfEmployees=20}
```

***How is it showing duplicate values in loop like hello1 as set is suppose to store only unique data.***

Answer (score 0):

It isn't an error. In order to know if an element is duplicated or not (when calling add, contains, etc...), the set checks its hashCode.
An HashSet stores its element into an array, using the element's hashCode as index.
`a1` and `a5` have different hashCode when you've added them to the set, so there is no collision.

By changing any property of the object its hasCode change, but the position in the set don't. Indeed `set.contains` will return false if you do so.

```
Set<Account> s = new Set<Account>();

Account a1 = new Account(Name='Hello1',NumberofEmployees=20);
s.add(a1);

a1.Site = 'test';
// the hashCode's changed so the set doesn't find a1...
System.assertEquals(false, s.contains(a1)); 

// ...and it can be added again to the set in a different position.
s.add(a1);
System.assertEquals(2, s.size());

Account a2 = new Account(Name='Hello1', NumberofEmployees=20, Site='Test');
// a2 has the same hashCode of a1, so you "find" it...
System.assertEquals(true, s.contains(a2));
// ...and if you add a2 to the set, the size will not change
s.add(a2);
System.assertEquals(2, s.size()); // no duplicate element has been added to the set
```

That's why you should prefer primitive types or immutable objects over mutable ones as keys for a Map.